# Glib C : program does not recognize GLIB library

Tags: c, glib

I have a problem with my C program, when I want to compile it. It works on Ubuntu 11.04, but when I move to Ubuntu 13 I get this problem.

I compile with this Makefile:

```
all:
    gcc -D_GNU_SOURCE -I/usr/include/glib-2.0 -I/usr/lib/glib-2.0/include \
    -I/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/glib-2.0/include/ -lglib-2.0 -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 \
    -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -g -Wall -Wextra -std=c99 -lm *.c -o concatener
```

I get these errors:

```
undefined reference to « g_str_equal »
undefined reference to « g_str_equal »
undefined reference to « g_array_remove_index »
undefined reference to « g_array_remove_index »
```

Why does it not recognize these functions? Have I linked to the glib library wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The gcc command looks fine, I cannot see anything obviously wrong, linking with `-lglib-2.0` should be what you want<sup>1</sup>.

What I am guessing is the case is that on your Ubuntu 11.04 system you have the glib development package installed while it is not installed on your 13 system. I think the package name should be libglib2.0-dev.

---

<sup>1</sup>
If you want to be a bit more generic you can replace the hardcoded compile and link options with

```
`pkg-config --cflags glib-2.0`
```

and

```
`pkg-config --libs glib-2.0`
```